# show the name of all players who scored a goal against Germany

Tags: sql

Select goals scored only by non-German players in matches where GER 
was the id of either team1 or team2.

join operation between game and goal table

GAME table:

```
 game id   mdate                  stadium          team1    team2
   1001  8 June 2012    National Stadium, Warsaw    POL     GRE
   1002  8 June 2012    Stadion Miejski (Wroclaw)   RUS     CZE
   1003  12 June 2012   Stadion Miejski (Wroclaw)   GRE     CZE
   1004  12 June 2012   National Stadium, Warsaw    POL     RUS
```

...

GOAL Table:

```
  matchid   teamid      player            gtime
   1001     POL     Robert Lewandowski     17
   1001     GRE     Dimitris Salpingidis   51
   1002     RUS     Alan Dzagoev           15
   1001     RUS     Roman Pavlyuchenko     82
```

...

```
  [1]: http://www.sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searched for the full question and I believe this should help. In the future, you may want to be a little more descriptive -

```
SELECT DISTINCT player
FROM game 
JOIN goal ON (matchid = id)
WHERE ( teamid != 'GER' AND (team1='GER' OR team2='GER' ))
```

Comment: the question didn't mentioed that id for Germany is 'GER', so I think we have to fetch that from eteam table.
So answer should be

SELECT DISTINCT goal.player
FROM goal
LEFT JOIN game
ON game.id = goal.matchid
LEFT JOIN eteam
ON eteam.id = game.team1 OR eteam.id = game.team2
WHERE eteam.teamname = 'Germany' AND goal.teamid <> eteam.id AND (eteam.id = game.team1 OR eteam.id = game.team2);

Comment: thats already provided in sql provided to create the data.